Gamma is multiplicative with Zeta - Is there an additive version?
There's a tension in number theory, with multiplication and addition. Tate's thesis is a way to relax some of this tension. It's known that the $\Gamma$ function has a multiplicative relationship with $\zeta$. It's also well known that $\zeta$ has a prime product rep. and a sum rep.
I will write them down now:
$$ \zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}=\prod_{\mathrm{p~prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$

Is it possible to have a function with an "additive" relation instead of "multiplicative" relation with $\zeta(s)$?

My proposed additive relation is:
$$I(s)=\zeta(s)+sf(s)$$
The usual multiplicative $\Gamma$ relation is:
$$ \zeta(s)\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^x-1}x^{s-1}~dx $$

Yes $$I(s)=2\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \int_{J=(0,n^{-s/2})} e^{\frac{\log^2({n^{s/2}})}{\log t}}~dt$$
and $$ f(s)=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \log n~K_1(s\log n)$$
where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function.
Here's a quick script to verify this claim: script. A neat physical interpretation of this is that we have Bessel waves that cancel each other out, and $\zeta$ is the standing wave that is left. (The nodes are the nontrivial zeros, $\rho_n$). This is in agreement with the sentiment of most number theorists that we know that zeta functions are related to vibration, nobody knows what is causing the vibration however.
If you squint hard enough, you'll see that those integrals are Mellin transforms re-written in a very particular way so as to extract the right information about the zeta function. And also, the integrand has a form reminiscient of the jacobi theta function. That is very roughly why the result holds. Because we are indeed transforming a disguised theta function so it's not a big surprise that the result involves zeta.
